# How to get the precision score of every class in a Multi class Classification Problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

I am making Sentiment Analysis Classification and I am doing it with Scikit-learn. This has 3 labels, positive, neutral and negative. The Shape of my training data is `(14640, 15)`, where

```
negative    9178
neutral     3099
positive    2363
```

I have pre-processed the data and applied the `bag-of-words` word vectorization technique to the text of twitter as there many other attributes too, whose size is then `(14640, 1000)`.
As the Y, means the label is in the text form so, I applied LabelEncoder to it. This is how I split my dataset -

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(bow, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)

out: (10248, 1000) (10248,)
     (4392, 1000) (4392,)
```

And this is my classifier

```
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, probability=True).fit(X_train, Y_train) 
prediction = svc.predict_proba(X_test) 
prediction_int = prediction[:,1] >= 0.3 
prediction_int = prediction_int.astype(np.int) 
print('Precision score: ', precision_score(Y_test, prediction_int, average=None))
print('Accuracy Score: ', accuracy_score(Y_test, prediction_int))

out:Precision score:  [0.73980398 0.48169243 0.        ]
Accuracy Score:  0.6675774134790529
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1437: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

Now I am not sure why the third one, in precision score is blank? I have applied `average=None`, because to make a separate precision score for every class. Also, I am not sure about the prediction, if it is right or not, because I wrote it for binary classification? Can you please help me to debug it to make it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your prediction results (test data), looks like none of the data point predicted as the third class

Comment: @SincoleBrans this has been already pointed out in the answer, and confirmed by the OP in the comments therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning explains:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
```

it seems that one of your 3 classes is **missing** from your *predictions* `prediction_int` (i.e. you never predict it); you can easily check if this is the case with

```
set(Y_test) - set(prediction_int)
```

which should be the empty set `{}` if this is *not* the case.

If this is indeed the case, and the above operation gives `{1}` or `{2}`, the most probable reason is that your dataset is imbalanced (you have much more `negative` samples), and you do not ask for a stratified split; modify your `train_test_split` to

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(bow, Y, test_size=0.3, stratify=Y, random_state=42)
```

and try again.

**UPDATE** (after comments):

As it turns out, you have a class imbalance problem (and not a *coding* issue) which prevents your classifier from successfully predicting your 3rd class (`positive`). Class imbalance is a huge sub-topic in itself, and there are several remedies proposed. Although going into more detail is arguably beyond the scope of a single SO thread, the first thing you should try (on top of the suggestions above) is to use the `class_weight='balanced'` argument in the definition of your classifier, i.e.:

```
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, probability=True, class_weight='balanced').fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

For more options, have a look at the dedicated [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) Python library (part of the [scikit-learn-contrib](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) projects).

Comment: did that, but when I do `set(Y_test) - set(prediction_int)`, gives me back `{2}`, so your words so true. Next I made `X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(bow, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)` to `X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(bow, Y, test_size=0.3, stratify=Y, random_state=42)` and run that, but still no result, same as before, like last precision is missing and `{2}`. Do you think anything is wrong with my prediction?

Comment: @DebPrakashChatterjee that's because in fact you don't have any *coding* issue (which arguably SO is all about), but a *data* issue (class imbalance). Notice that I just advised "try again" (and not "it should work", or something) - i.e. what I wrote is the correct action to do but still doesn't mean that it is *sufficient* for your imbalanced data...

Comment: That's pretty clear, but is there any option to do? I understand that this might fail, but I still wanna do this, I am near about completing my final project. So, I am requesting, is there any chance to succeed?

Comment: I got it, I have printed the `prediction_int`, and it turns out that, it is not printing the third class `[0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]`. Pretty problematic.

Comment: @DebPrakashChatterjee you mean, after using also `class_weights='balanced'`?

Comment: yes, after using `class_weights='balanced'`. I have updated my code too. please check,

Comment: @DebPrakashChatterjee pls do not alter the code after an answer has been provided - it makes the response look irrelevant (restored the previous edit); you have now arguably narrowed down the cause of your issue, and you may want to now open a **new** more focused question

Comment: this is the new thread link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401272/how-to-predict-all-classes-in-a-multi-class-sentiment-analysis-problem-using-svm/57401558#57401558